# Rails Routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

How does rails know how to map to each function in the controller if the `routes.rb` file only specifies:

```
resources :users
```

but inside the `UsersController` you have

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @user, :status => :created, :location => @user }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

How does rails determine that for instance the `index function maps` to `GET/users` while the `create function` maps to `POST/users`?

How does `resources :users` even know to map to the `UsersController`?

Comment: The Getting Started guide does a good job of explaining this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails is based around the 'convention over configuration' paradigm.

As such, the "resources :users" line indicates that all the standard CRUD methods are supported by the corresponding UsersController <-- the 'Users' prefix matches to the Controller, Model etc.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the rails routes guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

And to see in practice what the routes declaration does issue this command in your project directory:

> rake routes

Also as mentioned before, stick with conventions and remember that rails is a very opinionated piece of software.